# In Vertigo, how did Madeleine get inside her hotel room without the key?

Tags: plot-explanation, vertigo

One of the first clues that Madeleine is possessed by Carlotta's ghost is when Scottie sees her through a window at the McKittrick hotel, where Carlotta used to lived, but when he goes to the front desk he learns that no one checked in that day and the keys are still at reception.

How did Madeleine appear through the window then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertigo Scene Explanation - Did Hitchcock Cheat the Audience?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81974/vertigo-scene-explanation-did-hitchcock-cheat-the-audience)